# how to capture the error msg thrown by a unix system to another system where the script with commands to be executed on unix system was executed?

Tags: unix, scripting, ant

I am using ssh exec ant task in my script for executing some commands in unix system(change permission,etc)

i am executing these scripts from a distributed system. After the execution of the script,
In case of changing file permissions, the permissions are not changed as in the script.

How can i capture the error message that has been thrown by the unix system in the system we have executed the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `output` or `outputProperty` attributes of the [sshexec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html).